# How do you disable Just-in-Time debugging messages?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, debugging

In a relatively new installation of Windows Server 2008 R2, there are occasional popup messages about Just-in-time debugging. These may come up in w3wp.exe when a search bot accesses an aspx application. These messages are local Windows popups, not in browsers.

I cannot debug "just-in-time", however, because there are no and never have been any debuggers on the server. Microsoft is kind enough to tell my I don't have a VS2010 license to debug when I click debug. This makes the popup messages pretty useless, particularly since I typically don't see them until a few days after the fact.

How can I disable the Just-in-time debugging popup messages?

[image]

Comment: I think I'd be more inclined to try and fix the cause instead of hiding the effects. A crashing w3wp.exe process will also be affecting legitimate users of the application. Is this your code or a 3rd party application?

Comment: I can fix the causes, which are usually logged. That is a separate issue. The question is how to prevent the popup windows when an error does occur.

Comment: I have this problem on my sharepoint server too.  The crashes are inconsequential but the popups are irritating.

Comment: There is also [a similar posting, over at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20550317/107625), maybe this helps someone, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Remove the following Registry keys from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6%28VS.80%29.aspx)

- SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
- SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger
- SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
- SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger

Comment: I deleted the two AeDebug keys (and rebooted the server). The server does not have the DbgManagedDebugger keys. This made no difference -- the windows still appear.